# Error en Android Studio: 'emulator-5554' not found

Tags: android, android-studio

No consigo emular mi app, puesto que me surge el siguiente mensaje:

> Installation failed with message device 'emulator-5554' not found.
>   It is possible that this issue is resolved by uninstalling an existing version of the apk if it is present, and then re-installing.

He intentado reiniciar Android Studio y limpiar el proyecto (`clean project`). Al desinstalar la apk e intentar instalarla de nuevo, me dice:

> error installing apk

¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Comment: has intentado eliminar la aplicacion del emulador ? reinstalar el emulador ?

Answer (score 1):

Lo más  probable es que hayas actualizado el Emuladory no sus imagenes. Por lo que tienes que actualizar todo lo demás. Si te sale el letrero de que hay actualizaciones para el Emulator e Images descargalas todas.

Una vez actualizado todo crea un nuevo dispositivo virtual. Emulalo y corre sobre ese.

**Consejo:** Ya no actualices el SDK o el emulador.

Comment: si no aparece ese letrero, ¿Desde dónde puedo actualizarlo?

Answer (score 0):

Simplemente tu emulador no esta funcionando o no existe, por lo tanto no puede instalar el .apk, asegurar crear un AVD (Android virtual Device), en el cual se cargaría la aplicación.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[Crear y administrar dispositivos virtuales (AVD).](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/managing-avds.html?hl=es-419)

---

Otra razón indicada en el mensaje,

> Installation failed with message device 'emulator-5554' not found. It
>   is possible that this issue is resolved by uninstalling an existing
>   version of the apk if it is present, and then re-installing. He
>   intentado

la cual sinceramente nunca he experimentado (ya que al intentar subirla nueva versión del .apk la anterior es eliminada), es que si tu dispositivo virtual es visible, elimines la aplicación dentro del mismo.